# После обновление страницы на gh-pages вылазит ошибка 404

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Как избавится от проблемы что после обновление страницы на gh-pages вылазит ошибка 404. Но когда я обновляю главную страницу все хорошо ошибки нет, но стоит перейти на какую либо другую страницу и затем обновить ее она появляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Исправил таки образом
я писал на React так что буду обьеснять по нему
в папке public создал файл 404.html
и написал в нем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом перешол в файл index.html и в теге head написал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего зашел в index.js  и написал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в атрибуте basename написал название репозитория.

Вот так выглядит мой router

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после всех этих манипуляций все заработало
После обновления странице не выходит ошибка 404 и при переходе по ссылки тоже не приводит теперь к этой ошибке. Надеюсь помог кто искал на это ответ

Comment: Возможно вы еще не так указываете сылку в homepage в json. Она должна выглядеть так

  "homepage": "https://{ ваш ник }.github.io/{ название репозитория }",

Comment: да, на гитхабе целая [инструкция](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) как выкладывать приложения на реакт. выкладывается одной командой из консоли. клиентский роутинг (если он не на хешах) работать в гитхабе не будет, т.к. нужно правило, чтобы при всех вызовах вызывался главный обработчик с маршрутами. это можно сделать, например, в nginx. а в гитхаб страницах зайдете на какую-нибудь страницу, отличную от главной, нажмете обновить и получите 404